# A function not working when creating new row on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html table where I add rows dynamically when user clicks on a button. Two cell's number of each row of my table, should be multiplied. I made a function that can multiply 2 cell's number but when I create a new row by pressing `add button` the function does not work on the new row, it always works on first row on the table.

**Here is HTML code:**

```
<div class="table-responsive container">
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">SL.</th>
            <th scope="col">Item Description</th>
            <th scope="col">Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Qty.</th>
            <th scope="col">Total</th>
            <th scope="col">Del</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">1</th>
            <td><label>
                <input type="text" name="name">
            </label>
            </td>
            <td><label>
                <input type="text" id="price" oninput="calculate()">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="qt" oninput="calculate()">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="ttl" name='total'>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="remove">-</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <button id="addRow">+ Add</button>
</div>
```

**And here is the JavaScript code:**

```
let temp_td = '<tr>' +
    '<th scope="row">1</th>' +
    '<td><label><input type="text" name="name"></label></td>' +
    '<td><label><input type="text" id="price" oninput="calculate()"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" id="qt" oninput="calculate()"></td>' +
    '<td><input type="text" id="ttl" name="total"></td>' +
    '<td><button class="remove">-</button></td>' +
'</tr>';

$(function () {
    $('tbody').sortable();

    $('#addRow').click(function () {
        $('tbody').append(temp_td)
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.remove', function () {
        $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    });

    $('#getValues').click(function () {
        const total = [];
        let sum = 0;
        $('input[name="total"]').each(function (i, elem) {
            total.push($(elem).val())
        });
        for (let i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
            sum += Number(total[i])
        }
        console.log(total.join(','));
        console.log(total);
        console.log(sum);
        document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = sum;
        document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = sum + (sum * 5 / 100);

        // document.getElementById('total22').innerHTML = sum;
    })

});
function calculate() {
    var price = document.getElementById('price').value; 
    var qt = document.getElementById('qt').value;
    var ttl = document.getElementById('ttl');   
    var multiply = price * qt;
    ttl.value = multiply;
}
```

I tried to change so many things, but it's not working.

Comment: Looks like you duplicate IDs in your code every time you add a new row and that's a no no

Comment: So what can I do now? How can I create new row with new ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot duplicate the IDs in HTML. You can save the row number in a variable which you increment every time you add a new row, and use that variable to generate the IDs:

```js
$(function() {
  let row = 1;

  $('#addRow').click(function() {
    row++;
    let temp_td = '<tr><th scope="row">' + row + '</th><td><label><input type="text" name="name"></label></td><td><label><input type="text" id="price' + row + '" oninput="calculate(' + row + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="qt' + row + '" oninput="calculate(' + row + ')"></td><td><input type="text" id="ttl' + row + '" name="total"></td><td><button class="remove">-</button></td></tr>';
    $('tbody').append(temp_td)
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.remove', function() {
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
  });
});

function calculate(r) {
  var price = document.getElementById('price' + r).value;
  var qt = document.getElementById('qt' + r).value;
  var ttl = document.getElementById('ttl' + r);
  var multiply = price * qt;
  ttl.value = multiply;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-responsive container">
  <table class="table">
    <thead class="dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">SL.</th>
        <th scope="col">Item Description</th>
        <th scope="col">Price</th>
        <th scope="col">Qty.</th>
        <th scope="col">Total</th>
        <th scope="col">Del</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td><label>
                    <input type="text" name="name">
                </label>
        </td>
        <td><label>
                    <input type="text" id="price1" oninput="calculate(1)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="qt1" oninput="calculate(1)">
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" id="ttl1" name='total'>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class="remove">-</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <button id="addRow">+ Add</button>
```

You can also do that to the names if you like. I didn't do that in the code above because it is not essential for this answer.

Alternatively, you can pass the element itself to the `calculate()` function and then find the other "sibling" elements using jQuery. So you don't need IDs at all.

Comment: WOW thanks sir it helped me a lot I tried a lot but here you saved my time so many thanks

Comment: *temp_td* should probably be *temp_tr*. ;-)

Comment: @RobG Agreed :-)

Comment: I have another a little problem about the row count. So should create a new post or comment here? Row count start from 1 but if any row deleted it will count from 1 again.